# React HOC that takes argument instead of component and returns component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I create a React HOC that takes argument instead of component (let's say the argument is from useParams() of react router dom) and returns a component with the given argument (with hooks)

I tried

```js
import React from 'react'

const ResultsContent = searchValue => {
  const Content = props => {
    return (
      <h1>{searchValue}</h1>
    )
  }
  return Content
}

export default ResultsContent
```

then

```
let { value } = useParams()
const Content = ResultsContent(value)

return (
    <div>
      <Content></Content>
    </div>
)
```

and I got _results__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default(...) is not a function

Comment: What problems are you facing, and what have you tried yet?

Comment: I tried to create a function that takes the argument and then inside the function I created the component then the function returns the component. so I exported this function and it didn't work

Comment: Could you provide your current code?

Comment: `const ResultsContent = searchValue => {
  const Content = props => {
    return (
      <h1>{searchValue}</h1>
    )
  }
  return Content
}

export default ResultsContent`

Comment: then `const Content = ResultsContent(value)`

Comment: Update your question, please.

Comment: Sure, I updated it. i'm new here so I just saw how to update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could do something like this:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const resultsContent = (searchValue) => {
  const Content = (props) => <h1>{searchValue}</h1>;
  return Content;
};
const Content = resultsContent("a");

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Content />, rootElement);
```

**Also check if you import your `ResultsContent` with a default import not named import:

`import ResultsContent from './your-path-to-the-file';`**

Comment: Thanks! it works, it was the import like you said